# How can I fill NaN values in a Pandas DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, data-cleaning, kaggle

I am trying to learn data analysis and machine learning by trying out some problems.

I found a [competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) "House prices" which is actually a playground competition. Since I am very new to this field, I got confused after exploring the data. The data has 81 columns out of which 1 is the target column which is the house value. This data contains multiple columns where majority of values are "NaN". When I ran:

```
nulls = data.isnull().sum()
nulls[nulls > 0]
```

This shows the columns with missing values:

```
LotFrontage     259 
Alley           1369
MasVnrType      8   
MasVnrArea      8   
BsmtQual        37  
BsmtCond        37  
BsmtExposure    38  
BsmtFinType1    37  
BsmtFinType2    38  
Electrical      1   
FireplaceQu     690 
GarageType      81  
GarageYrBlt     81  
GarageFinish    81  
GarageQual      81  
GarageCond      81  
PoolQC          1453
Fence           1179
MiscFeature     1406
```

At this point I am totally lost and I don't know how to get rid of these "NaN" values.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `DataFrame.fillna` function to fill the `NaN` values in your data. For example, assuming your data is in a DataFrame called `df`,

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

will replace the missing values with the constant value `0`. You can also do more clever things, such as replacing the missing values with the mean of that column:

```
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
```

or take the last value seen for a column:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Filling the `NaN` values is called *imputation*. Try a range of different imputation methods and see which ones work best for your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The dataset also consists of string values. I think `df.fillna()` will work on float or integer values. Any pointers on converting string values to numeric values?

Comment: Ah, I had assumed the data was numeric for some reason. By string values, do you mean categorical data i.e. strings from a particular set of values? Then, you can use [scikit-learn's LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). Natural language, on the other hand, is more difficult to deal with. Bag-of-words is probably the easiest to think about, but have a look at [these](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) options.

Comment: "`inplace` is evil": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not

Answer (score 1):

```
  # Taking care of missing data
  from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
  imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
  imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
  X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

suppose the name of my array is $X$ and I want to take care of missing data in columns  indexed $1$ and  $2$ by replacing it with mean. Imputer is a great class to do this from sklearn library

Answer (score 0):

While Tim Earhart has already provided the answer, I would like to add here there are cases when rather than using `choosing df.mean()` to substitute your NA values, it is better to choose `df.median()` - which calculates your median value.

Mean is notorious for taking into consideration even the outliers.

Since you are a beginner, you might want to try both.